# Why isn't Xcode building the second target of my project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I've downloaded an Xcode project (a [QR code encoder](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C)) that has two products:

- a library
- a demo which uses the library

When I do a build or a run, it just builds the library.

How do I configure Xcode to build both targets, and load the demo app when I do "run"?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.2.

Comment: repost of screeshot -->  http://ksucat.com/xc.png

Comment: I found it, click on scheme button (right of stop button)  then  "edit scheme"  then pick the demo target from the top dropdown.  it originally had the lib selected, I changed that to demo and compiled.  it compiled both targets and download the app to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I left my answer in the comments section.

The build scheme had the lib and target in a drop-down with the lib selected.

When I changed that selection from lib to demo and rebuilt it build both targets and downloaded the demo app to my phone.